# Opengl sometimes works funnily

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I want to draw 2 circles, and here are the necessary bits from three files of my project.

circle.h

```
#include "main.h"

#ifndef CIRCLE_H
#define CIRCLE_H

class Circle{
public:
    Circle(){};
    Circle(float x, float y, float radius, float fraction, color_t color);
    void set_position(float x, float y);
    void draw(glm::mat4 VP);
    bounding_box_t bounding_box();

    glm::vec3 position;
    float rotation;
    float radius;
    float fraction;


private:
    VAO *object;

};
#endif //CIRCLE_H
```

circle.cpp

```
#include "circle.h"
#include "main.h"
#include <iostream>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

typedef struct {
        GLfloat x;
        GLfloat y;
        GLfloat z;
    }point;

point rotate_by(double angle, point inp_point){
    point new_point;
    new_point.x = inp_point.x*cos(angle) - inp_point.y*sin(angle);
    new_point.y = inp_point.x*sin(angle) + inp_point.y*cos(angle);
    return new_point;
};

void fill_array(int sides, float radius, int fraction, GLfloat array[]){
    double angle = 2 * PI / sides;

    point vertex;
    vertex.x = 0.0f;
    vertex.y = 0.0f;
    vertex.z = 0.0f;

    point oldpoint;
    oldpoint.x = 0.0f;
    oldpoint.y = radius;
    oldpoint.z = 0.0f;

    int iterations = (int)(fraction*sides);
    std::cout<< iterations <<std::endl;

    //For each triangle
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
        // setting the vertex
        array[9*i + 0] = vertex.x;
        array[9*i + 1] = vertex.y;
        array[9*i + 2] = vertex.z;

        // setting the oldpoint
        array[9*i + 3] = oldpoint.x;
        array[9*i + 4] = oldpoint.y;
        array[9*i + 5] = oldpoint.z;

        // making the new point
        point newpoint = rotate_by(angle, oldpoint);

        // setting the new point
        array[9*i + 6] = newpoint.x;
        array[9*i + 7] = newpoint.y;
        array[9*i + 8] = newpoint.z;

        // New point is now old
        oldpoint = newpoint;
    }

};

Circle::Circle(float x, float y, float radius, float fraction, color_t color) {
    this->position = glm::vec3(x, y, 0);
    this->rotation = 0;
    int sides = 50;
    this->radius = radius;
    this->fraction = fraction;
    static GLfloat vertex_buffer_data[1000]; 
    fill_array(sides, radius, fraction, vertex_buffer_data);
    int num_vertices = (int)(fraction*sides)*3;
    std::cout << num_vertices <<std::endl;

    this->object = create3DObject(GL_TRIANGLES, num_vertices, vertex_buffer_data, color, GL_FILL);
}

void Circle::draw(glm::mat4 VP) {
    Matrices.model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 translate = glm::translate (this->position);    // glTranslatef
    glm::mat4 rotate    = glm::rotate((float) (this->rotation * M_PI / 180.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
    rotate          = rotate * glm::translate(glm::vec3(0, -0.6, 0));
    Matrices.model *= (translate * rotate);
    glm::mat4 MVP = VP * Matrices.model;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(Matrices.MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
    draw3DObject(this->object);
}
```

main.cpp

```
//-------------------Necessary tools----------------------------------------------
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include "timer.h"
#include "main.h"
using namespace std;

//------------------Template Imports---------------------------------------------
#include "circle.h"

//---------------Important declarations-------------------------------------------
GLMatrices Matrices;
GLuint     programID;
GLFWwindow *window;
float screen_zoom = 1, screen_center_x = 0, screen_center_y = 0;
Timer t60(1.0 / 60);


//--------------Object declarations-----------------------------------------------
Circle c1;
Circle c2;

// -------------Functions----------------------------------------------------------
void draw() {

    //---------Don't touch---------------------------------------------------------
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram (programID);
    Matrices.view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0, 0, 3), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)); // Fixed camera for 2D (ortho) in XY plane
    glm::mat4 VP = Matrices.projection * Matrices.view;
    glm::mat4 MVP;  

    //---------Scene render--------------------------------------------------------
    c1.draw(VP);
    c2.draw(VP);
}


void initGL(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height) {
    //-----------Create objects----------------------------------------------
        c1 = Circle(1,1,1.0f,1.0f,COLOR_BLACK);
        c2 = Circle(2,2,1.0f,1.0f, COLOR_RED);




    //-----------Don't touch-------------------------------------------------
    programID = LoadShaders("Sample_GL.vert", "Sample_GL.frag");
    Matrices.MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
    reshapeWindow (window, width, height);
    glClearColor (COLOR_BACKGROUND.r / 256.0, COLOR_BACKGROUND.g / 256.0, COLOR_BACKGROUND.b / 256.0, 0.0f); // R, G, B, A
    glClearDepth (1.0f);
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc (GL_LEQUAL);
    cout << "VENDOR: " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << endl;
    cout << "RENDERER: " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << endl;
    cout << "VERSION: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << endl;
    cout << "GLSL: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    srand(time(0));
    int width  = 600;
    int height = 600;
    window = initGLFW(width, height);
    initGL (window, width, height);

    /* Draw in loop */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        // Process timers

        if (t60.processTick()) {
            // 60 fps
            // OpenGL Draw commands
            draw();
            // Swap Frame Buffer in double buffering
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);

            tick_elements();
            //tick_input(window);
        }

        // Poll for Keyboard and mouse events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    quit(window);
}


void reset_screen() {
    float top    = screen_center_y + 4 / screen_zoom;
    float bottom = screen_center_y - 4 / screen_zoom;
    float left   = screen_center_x - 4 / screen_zoom;
    float right  = screen_center_x + 4 / screen_zoom;
    Matrices.projection = glm::ortho(left, right, bottom, top, 0.1f, 500.0f);
}
```

For some reason, sometimes, I get the right output, but sometimes, I get funny outputs.

This is the correct image that I want:
[image: This is the correct output I would like.]

But several times nothing appears at all:
[image: But several times nothing appears at all]

Sometimes really funny outputs appear, like this:
[image: Sometimes really funny outputs appear, like this]

... And this:
[image: ... And this.]

Notice that I am not even running make again and again, these variations happen each time I am opening the executable itself.

How can I get the correct output every time?

Comment: That probably means there's something wrong in one of the transformations. Why don't you monitor the value of world and view transformations in all of those cases?

Comment: @Asesh, but the transformations are the same each time, right? And I do get the correct answer 50 percent of the time, so it should be something that changes everytime you run the executable?

Comment: Try running your program with `valgrind`, it will report uninitialized data if you tried to use any.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: your question looks ok to me, but you should consider addressing the provided answer to see if solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

Do you call `reset_screen()` function somewhere? Because in this function you are creating your projection matrix. It looks like this matrix is uninitialized (initialized with some trash).

Comment: I called it before projecting, but that didn't help